# Can you stop and hang out in hyperspace?

Tags: star-wars, hyperspace

Looking back at *Rogue One* and *Return of the Jedi*, where Rebel fleets coordinate jumping into hyperspace to arrive at the same time, I started wondering whether it's possible to stop moving in hyperspace.

For example, navigate to a system, "stop" and then drop into realspace for a perfectly timed ambush.

One piece of evidence against this idea is that the Emperor had the fleet hide behind the Forest Moon of Endor instead of hiding out in hyperspace.

Has any ship in canon ever stopped in hyperspace without dropping out?

Comment: Travelling at hyperspace requires faster than light travel, stopping would mean slowing down below the speed of light, and therefore exiting hyperspace.

Comment: I thought hitting lightspeed pushed you into hyperspace, an alternate dimension.

Comment: AFAIK, no, but I don't know much, so one of the "experts" will probably be round soon

Comment: Possible dupe of [Was it a mistake that the X-Wings in The Force Awakens were waiting in hyperspace?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115172/was-it-a-mistake-that-the-x-wings-in-the-force-awakens-were-waiting-in-hyperspac)?

Comment: @Valorum The answer to that question explains that the X-Wings were just taking the scenic route in hyperspace, and changed directions when they got orders. As far as I can tell, the X-Wings aren't described in the novelization or script as waiting while stopped.

Comment: @Edlothiad - Yeah, it does.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai, there's the expert

Comment: @Edlothiad - When I say,"it does," though, I mean that it does put one in a separate dimension. FTL travel through realspace is just as impossible in Star Wars as in real life.

Comment: I can, and I do!

Comment: If it was possible to stop in hyperspace without dropping out, it would likely be possible to set up an entire *base* there. That could have given the rebels a nice way to hide out.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Just wild speculation, that would probably  be a huge power drain.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai possibly, but it could be a wash with or even better than the cost of relocating your forces and rebuilding your base every two years when the Empire finds your old one. Those shield generators and downed speeders and X-Wings aren't *free*.

Answer (score 4):

**You can't**.

In Star Wars Rebels, episode 7 of season 1, Kanan and Ezra exit the Ghost by detaching a hyperspace-capable shuttle, the Phantom, which, since it was docked, doesn't have his own momentum. What happens is they are *violently* ejected from hyperspace when they fall behind the Ghost (appereantly there's "air" resistance in hyperspace, and you lose momentum).

Comment: Your video doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 1):

The rational for Hyperspace is a drive that changes state of the vehicle into another dimension when it is traveling faster than light (or at light speed) BUT it must be moving at or faster than light speed for this to work. It is crucial not to accidentally travel to close to where a star or some other solid mass is - as they cast a MASS SHADOW and being too close would cause bad events.

The entire premise of this is that the vehicle must be in motion - you could choose to take a detour, but you could not choose to just stop still. Doing so would drop you out.

Taking an unplanned detour would be a bad idea - you really REALLY would not want to accidentally run too close to somethings mass shadow.

Comment: Nooooooo, hyperspace is a separate dimension in *Star Wars*. Yes, there are mass shadows cast by objects, but it really is a separate dimension.

Comment: I’m downvoting because of this. Perhaps you could edit your answer to focus on the actual rules/“physics” of hyperspace? You’re not too far off.

Comment: @Adament  Thanks for the heads up - I've corrected my mistake in the answer here.

Comment: I reversed my downvote, if that’s what you’re wondering. Parts of this are still incorrect, though.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. To drop out of hyper space for an ambush you would have to know exactly when and where a ship will be, then time it just right to drop out in the right area right when the ship arrives which means the most effective way to do this is to plot a course for that destination and figure out how to time it perfectly to go into hyperspace and arrive at just the right time to ambush that person. But I don't think you can just hang out in hyperspace. It would be like trying to stay still in a raft on the rapids.